# Why does valgrind print: error writing 36 bytes to shared mem /tmp/vgdb-pipe-shared-mem-vgdb-2758-by-root-on-?

Tags: valgrind

During start valgrind prints the following and terminates silently.  Why does that happen and what does it mean?

```
==2758== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2758== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2758== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2758== Command: /usr/local/bin/bp_mat_00
==2758==
==2758== error writing 36 bytes to shared mem /tmp/vgdb-pipe-shared-mem-vgdb-2758-by-root-on-???
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that valgrind attempts to write to a directory that is already full. See

```
df -h
```

However if the directory gets filled at a later stage of valgrind run then valgrind may not print that message, may not terminate, but still may work incorrectly...